# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, zoho

I've angular cli project that hosted in azure and I'm making API call to different domain (in Zoho creator) so I have CROS issue I tried some solutions with no luck.

The error is

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://xxxxxxx" from origin "https://yyyyyy" has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I use expressJS as my backend and I tried to add headers but it seems not working I don't know what I'm  missing

APP.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();  
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
var cors = require('cors');
// Use this after the variable declaration
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5000');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

//Set Port
const port = process.env.PORT || '5000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize exactly what It's happening but there's something that it makes me noise.

```
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5000');
```

This code indicate that you can only receive requests from http://localhost:5000. Are you trying to consume it from http://localhost:5000? I don't think so because the port 5000 is being used by node.js. if you want to use it, you must set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to the Server or Site where you're trying consume it from.

Example, I have a application in Angular in my machine using the port 4200, so the request header should be:

```
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
```

Or, you can use * to allow everything but It's not secure.

```
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: yes, you are correct but even when I use * to allow everything the same problem occurs