# Getting CORS error when using Passport Azure AD

Tags: node.js, express, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, passport-azure-ad

I have my Express API server as well as the SPA hosted on Heroku. The SPA uses Azure ad authentication using MSAL. The APIs are secured using Passport-azure-ad. Everything was working well in my localhost and the requests made where getting a success response. However on uploading the changes to Heroku I am now getting the CORS error. I have registered the API on Azure AD and exposed the API to my SPA. Any reason why I am still getting the error?

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myTestApp-server.herokuapp.com/getUsers' from origin 'https://myTestApp.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exposed the API to my SPA"? Did you allow the origin `https://myTestApp.herokuapp.com` for CORS requests to your server?

Comment: Yes I have added that as well in my server but it still says No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, even though i see in network tab that the header is present

Comment: That's important information you should put into the question (not into a comment).

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid the CORS error, make sure to add the header like below:**

- While adding the Allowed origins use **`*`** to allow all like below:

[image]

- Otherwise, add particular origins like below:

[image]

- Make sure to **restart** the Api after making the above changes.
- Check whether you are using correct **version** of NodeJs that matches the runtime you’re developing and testing.
- Try modifying **CORS** policy by adding **`.SetIsOriginAllowed((host)=> true)"`**
- If you are adding header via Nodejs code make use of below command:

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Or

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
https://myTestApp-server.herokuapp.com:4200');
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Azure App Service No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853588/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-in)

[3 Ways to Fix the CORS Error and How the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Works](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)